# Is there a performance difference when we encrypt a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am just wondering to whether is there any performance difference in stored procedures and inline queries when database encryption is turned on?

If yes, could you explain when the performance is good and when it's bad?

Comment: of course there is some overhead. Nothing is free....

Comment: Perhaps this might be of interest: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3815501/Performance-Testing-SQL-2008146s-Transparent-Data-Encryption.htm

Comment: @Mitch-SO in SQl server 2008 TDE is to protect the data from theift and it wil not do any improvements in performance as well it will not degrade the performance?

Answer (score 2):

from my DBA experience with SQL2008, there's very little performance impact for the end user, and the reason is this:

The encryption only takes place when writing  to, and reading from, to the database file (.DBF) and the backups. Once the data is in memory, it is unencrypted and queries run just as fast as they do normally.

The whole encryption process used to be hidious in SQL 2005 and there was a notable performance penalty, but with SQL 2008, the process of encrypting tables or entire databases takes only a few minutes (and the directions are easy to follow - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098(v=sql.100).aspx).

The process basically takes three steps:

1. create the public/private cert keys (there's a stored procedure for that).
2. turn on the encryption for the db.
3. then save db.

The database being encrypted will switch to single-user mode for a minute or two while the database file is re-written in encrypted form, but it doesn't take long. The conversion of a 50GB file, for instance, takes a couple minutes at the most.

Good luck and make sure you **don't lose the certificate keys**! Email them to yourself, because if you ever need to recover from backup or move the MDF file to another server, you're screwed without the cert files. (Don't worry, it's all spelled out in the MS documentation I listed).

Comment: It is generally thought that a fairly cautious mindset is appropriate when dealing with security issues. With that in mind, it is probably worth considering that once a private certificate is emailed to anyone, it should be considered compromised (due to interception either in transit or at rest on an email provider's server). Perhaps one could be less cautious if the keys are encrypted with a strong passphrase, but there are surely use-cases where even that is not thought to be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

@AnandPhadke - What Mitch meant is that there *will* be overhead. Encrypting and decrypting will need to be done, so there is overhead whenever either of those operations take place.

> In the Enterprise and Developer editions of the software SQL Server
>   2008, a new security feature of transparent data encryption (TDE) has
>   been included. It has a slightly negative overall performance impact
>   on the SQL Server optimization. It is to the extent of 3 to 5 %.
>   However, if most of the data is stored in memory, the impact is
>   lesser.

Source: [SQL Server Optimization And The Performance Impact Of Encryption](http://www.streetdirectory.com/travel_guide/125755/security/sql_server_optimization_and_the_performance_impact_of_encryption.html)

> “The tempdb system database will be encrypted if any other database on
>   the instance of SQL Server is encrypted by using TDE. This might have
>   a performance effect for unencrypted databases on the same instance of
>   SQL Server. For more information about the tempdb system database, see
>   tempdb Database.”

Source: [Transparent Data Encryption (TDE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx)